# Path Location to Remote IIS

Tags: c#, iis

I'm having a unique problem with Internet Information System.

I have several hosted web-sites. Each site contains an *Application Pool* and *Web Site*.  However when they leave their *paid status* and become expired.  I've designed a service to modify the web-sites **physical path**.

An example:

```
private static void ExpireSite(string url)
{
     using(ServerManaged manager = new ServerManager())
     {
          Site expire = manager.Sites[url];
          expire.Applications[url].Path = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Expired";
          manager.CommitChanges();
     }
}
```

It doesn't modify the path, but I do manage to get an **Invalid Path Error**.

The `url` parameter matches the web-site name and directory within the root IIS Folder.

I've followed the Microsoft Developer Network, but unfortunately the article doesn't outline this process very well.

Does anyone know if this is the proper way to find the *Physical Path*? Is this MSDN article even accurate?

I'd like to add that the documented way, doesn't work:

```
private static void ExpireSite(string url)
{
     using(ServerManaged manager = new ServerManager())
     {
          Site expire = manager.Sites[url];
          expire.Applications[url].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Expired";
          manager.CommitChanges();
     }
}
```

I receive the same error, both ways.

---

**Update:**

For the sake of argument I ran some additional test; I've got around three hundred web-sites.  When I run:

```
using(ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
{
     Site domain = manager.Sites[url];
     foreach(Application app in expire.Applications)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(domain.Id);
         Console.WriteLine(domain.Name); 
         Console.WriteLine(app.Path);
      }
}
```

It retrieves their data, but they all have the same path of `/`.  That doesn't seem correct; so if I use this:

```
domain.Applications[@"/"].VirtualDirectories[@"/"].PhysicalPath = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Expired";
```

It does indeed change the path, but should they all contain the `/` path?

Comment: I think that if you take a look at the list of virtual directories for each application, you answer that last question. When I was running the code below, all of the virtual directories under an application had a "/" at the beginning of the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### New Answer

First, I still stand by the statement that the [Application.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.application.path.aspx) information isn't being used correctly. Path is meant to be a virtual path not the physical path. Second, I believe that the problem with your original code to get the target application is a simple problem. Namely, that the string you should be using is "/" + url rather than just the url.

To demonstrate this, I set up a new site on my local IIS with an application using the same name as the site

[image: IIS Setup]

The physical path of the application under the site can be seen here:

[image: Physical Path Original]

I then put together a method to get the target site "mylocalsite.hereiam.com", the app under it with the same name and then attempt to update the path using both the app's Path property as well as the default virtual directory of the app's physical path.

```
    public static void SetPathTest()
    {
        using (var manager = new ServerManager())
        {
            const string Url = "mylocalsite.hereiam.com";

            var targsite = manager.Sites[Url];

            var targapp = targsite.Applications["/" + Url];
            var worked = false;

            Console.WriteLine("App path: {0}", targapp.Path);

            try
            {
                targapp.Path = @"C:\Projects\Demos\OData\Station.ODataNew";
                Console.WriteLine("Setting Path using Path worked!");
                worked = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Oops. Path isn't settable this way");
            }

            if (!worked)
            {
                try
                {
                    targapp.VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath = @"C:\Projects\Demos\OData\Station.ODataNew";
                    Console.WriteLine("Setting path using the Virtual directory worked!");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Oops. Virtual directory PhysicalPath isn't settable this way");
                }
            }

            manager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
```

The result of running this is:

[image: Result]

And the physical path was changed:

[image: Physical Path Changed]

Hopefully, this is more helpful than the first go around.

### Old Answer

I think that based on the documentation in the documentation for [Application.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.application.path.aspx), the value you're putting into the property should be "/Expired" instead of "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Expired". If you want to use the full path, [PhysicalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.virtualdirectory.physicalpath.aspx) of the VirtualDirectories property is the correct property to set.

Comment: First, I'm not looking for the down vote to go away. My answer is not really helpful. That being said, I think that using the url to get the site might be incorrect. I was playing around with the servermanager object, and the only way I was able to get access to a site was through the actual name such as "Default Web Site". Using a URL didn't work at all. I was however able to change the physical path using the VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath property.

Comment: But I'm not utilizing virtual directories or default site name.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, the only reason the `parameter` URL should work in my case; the name of the directory and site is the URL.  As you'll see the `Application[]` will accept the integer index value or the string name.